# Is it possible to unwarp this piece of wood?

Tags: wood, warp

First time working with wood - i CNC'd a landscape into a piece of London Plane timber but since first purchasing the wood, the left hand side of it has slowly curled upwards. Most of the curling happened over the weekend when it was left sitting on a table - oops. I assume the thinner part has dried out faster than elsewhere, causing it to shrink on the side that was exposed over the weekend.

I've been spraying the surface lightly with water every day, and now leaving the underside exposed. Since doing that, it appears to have unwarped by around 30%.

Are there any further ways to unwarp this without damaging / fracturing the piece of wood?[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. There are multiple things going on here, including the issues you've already identified. In addition this is a flat-sawn piece (a slice straight across a log) which have a natural tendency to warp, and on top of that there are natural defects so the wood itself is definitely a big part of the problem. We have a couple of previous Q&As on methods to fix warps but the bottom line is that you can't reliably fix them in the long term (and the methods for the attempt usually require free access to both sides of the board).

Comment: Have you considered just putting feet under it to make it sit level and calling it done?

Comment: Thanks Graphus, I didn't consider the direction of the grain but that makes alot of sense. It hasn't warped any further in the past week so I will leave it as it, I don't mind the slight warping but was hoping it wouldn't turn into the profile of a banana as it dries out. That's a good point Aloysius, I will be raising it slightly to reduce the effect of the warping and will possibly also chamfer the edge profile if need be.